# After Updating to SHA2, private and public doesn't match

Tags: ssh, rsa, public-key-encryption, sha-2

I've upgraded to SHA2 certificate, but after upgrading the new certificate key doesn't match my old private key.

Public key has changed after updating and it doesn't match to previous private key.

Is it usual that after upgrading to SHA2, the upgrading public key doesn't match previous SHA1's private key ?

Any pointer's will be helpful ?

Comment: Did you mean to tag the question with `ssl`, not `ssh`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it *might* be normal. It depends on how the "upgrade" was done.

Usually the keypair is created by *you*, and the CA merely signs it to create a certificate out of the public key it was given. So *you* should try to remember whether you chose to use the old key or to generate a new one when you created the new certificate-request.